# How do I display the already uploaded images in a custom form?

Tags: forms, 9

I build a custom form to edit nodes, which have a *multiple files* field I show using the following code.

```php
$files = $event->field_bijlages;
$fileIds = [];

foreach($files as $file) {
  $fileIds[] = $file->entity->fid->value;
}

$form['files'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#default_value' => $fileIds,
  '#upload_location' => 'public://',
);
```

How do I allow users to add new uploaded images and delete the already uploaded ones?

Comment: @cilefen I tried it exactly like that by doing as you can see in my post. But it sadly does not print anything for me.

Comment: Oh wait it works now, but it's just showing the filenames, I'm not able to select a specific one and delete it.

Comment: This question isn't about the value to use for #default_value. It's not a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182874/default-value-of-a-managed-file-field.